# Ruby on the rails relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, activerecord

I have users and projects. User can have many projects and project can have many users. Now project has a particular user as an author or the creator, ie. project has one creator and that creator is also a user. How do I map this relation in rails !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Project
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
belongs_to :author, :class_name => "User"

#User
has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
has_many :authored_projects, :class_name => "Project", :foreign_key => "author_id"
```

And you need to add `author_id` to the projects table.

So you can use: `project.author`, `user.authored_projects`, etc

Comment: What should I do if I want do like project = User.last.projects.create(params[:projects]), currently by doing this values are not set up in the join table, ie. I am not being able to get project.users by doing project = User.last.projects.create(params[:projects])

Comment: @roxxypoxxy, strange, but it should work: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_and_belongs_to_many-association-reference look at 4.4.1.15. The new entry should be created in ProjectsUsers table.

Comment: okay i can do user1.projects << project1 and project1.users << user2,    what should we do if we want author_id to be set by doing            `project2 = user1.projects.new #should set the author of project2 to user1`

Comment: `project2 = user1.authored_projects.new`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
 has_many :created_projects, :class_name => "Project", :foreign_key => "creator_id"    
end



class Project< ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :users  
 belongs_to :creator, :class_name => "User"
end
```

Comment: I think you don't need specify `foreign_key` in `Project`, it's not necessary: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555984/rails-foreign-key-column-name-convention-for-a-unary-many-many-relation Also, it is necessary to establish a connection between the creator and his projects.